# how to insert a string value from an XML to the offset account segmented textbox in AX?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to insert values into the segmented text box of the **Offset Account Type**

[image]

I will be placing strings, I would be placing only values for Main Account, and Cost Center and the rest would be Not Applicable (zeros)

```
offsetcon = [lineItemsNode.selectSingleNode("GLAccount").text(), "00","00",lineItemsNode.selectSingleNode("CostCenter").text(),"0000","000","000","00000","000","00"];
            trans.parmOffsetLedgerDimension(AxdDimensionUtil::getLedgerAccountId(offsetcon));
```

I have tried the code above and I get the error that

> Main Acount 00 does not exist

from what I know is that Main Account is the first index in the container, and the error says its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to what I've found out...

The offset account has a segmented value, if you're going to pass a string/text to it, it must be placed in a container.

```
offsetContainer =[ MainAccount, MainAccount, *Number of Dimensions*, *Name of the Dimension*, *Value of the Dimension*, ... ];
```

**...** - means more can be added.
*Disregard the asterisks (*).*

The first two segments are the **MainAccount** (I am really not sure on the first segment, please correct me if I am wrong. But I've researched about it and it has a different value than the second, in my case I used the same value as the second segment and it worked for me.), then the next is the **Number of Dimensions**. This is the number of segments that you're going to place a value after the MainAccountId, then the **Name of the Dimensions** is name of the segment. Lastly, the **Value of the Dimension** this is the value you're going to assign to the dimension you just named.

So here's an example of a segment.

[image: Here's an example of a segment]

and here is how you will code the container:

```
offsetContainer = [ 1101006, 
                    1101006, 
                    5, 
                    'BudORProject',
                    '00',
                    'Local_OverSeas',
                    '00',
                    'ProfitCenter',
                    '0000',
                    'Hub',
                    '000' 
                            ];
```

So since there are 5 more segments after the MainAccount, **5** is the value for the **Number of Dimensions**. *

Now using it on your code:

```
AxLedgerJournalTrans    trans   = new AxLedgerJournalTrans();
trans.parmOffsetLedgerDimension(AxdDimensionUtil::getLedgerAccountId(offsetcon));
```

Don't forget to use AxdDimensionUtil::getLedgerAccountId method where you will place the container, as seen above.

Comment: Related: [Passing Financial Dimension combination values in ax 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047920/passing-financial-dimension-combination-values-in-ax-2012)